# Powershell - Exchange 2013 filing script

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server

I have been looking through the http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/ website to no avail and was wondering if someone could help me please.

I would like to create a script that runs for every single email that is sent through exchange 2013. This script looks for an id email attribute that the email is assigned by my other script and if it has an id attribute the email will be moved to a shared mailbox on the exchange and put into a folder with the same id or create a new one if one doesn't exist.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please divide your problem up in smaller parts and see if you can solve them one by one. It is hard to believe you could not write a single line of code. What exactly is the problem you can't solve yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Dint understand the query fully.
Looks like u want to write some code that will be executed for all the emails flowing through exchange.

Then Transport Agents are the way to go.

Here's the link which gives the documentaion regarding tranpsort agents in Exchange 2013.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204097(v=exchg.150).aspx

You want to look for an "attribute" in the email and redirect emails based on that.
May be u can look for a message header in an email via transport agent and based on that perform redirection in the agent(removing all the recipients and adding 'redirectmailbox' as the only recipient).

You can also add custom headers to an email via transport agents.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mstehle/archive/2009/01/13/howto-sample-transport-agent-add-headers-categories-mapi-props-even-uses-a-fork.aspx

Transport Agents act on all the emails flowing through the orgnanisation.
Use them with caution.